# Custom Horizontal Scroll View with picker

Tags: android, android-scrollview

The user needs to enter their weight in the sign up page of my App, for which a horizontal scroll view is created, on which the center element data will be taken as the user's height in inches.

[image]

I tried implementing the Spinner Wheel Library from [Android SpinnerWheel](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel) but it supports only `int` values and does not support fractions.

I also tried the [Android HorizontalScrollView with Center Lock](http://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/tag/horizontal-scrollview-with-auto-center-lock/) library but it does not support auto scrolling.

Can anyone please suggest some examples or tips to implement the above mentioned scroll view with the center element value taken as the field entry?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You found anything? I am trying to implement a same thing for date

Comment: @woooh77 If it still actual, maybe this will help to someone: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34049368/2450152

Comment: Thanks. Will check it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use recycler view and set it to scroll horizontally instead of using any custom library.

```
     RecyclerView recycler= (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);

     LinearLayoutManager llManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mcontext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(llManager);
```

Then to centeralize your desire location, Refer [Recyclerview scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25718992/3817374). And customise it as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this open source library](https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker). Its licensed under Apache 2.0. I believe we can modify the code of it to suite the requirements